# Plotly logarithmic candlesticks scale

Tags: python, plotly, finance, logarithm

Plotly make great figures. Plotly express can change the scale easely with the parameter "`log_y=True`". I wonder how can it be done with plotly candlesticks class without changing or altering the original data.

Reviewing documentation, I get lost with so many examples, but cannot find this.

**Code to reproduce:**

```
ohlc = np.array([[21318.58   , 21333.63   , 21296.43   , 21306.91   ,   198.6474 ],
       [21306.92   , 21310.51   , 21216.49   , 21235.99   ,   216.02765],
       [21235.98   , 21249.64   , 21128.41   , 21204.33   ,   495.20652],
       [21204.33   , 21238.26   , 21169.69   , 21198.37   ,   185.9797 ],
       [21198.36   , 21205.54   , 21154.     , 21165.01   ,   208.91714],
       [21165.     , 21230.     , 21165.     , 21229.99   ,   130.70106],
       [21229.99   , 21280.45   , 21217.32   , 21269.24   ,   162.83325],
       [21269.24   , 21279.51   , 21250.     , 21261.2    ,   143.27844],
       [21261.21   , 21278.19   , 21260.05   , 21260.66   ,    82.78135]])

ohlc = np.reshape(ohlc, (9,5))

df = pd.DataFrame(data=ohlc, columns=['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'])

import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df.index,
                                     open=df['open'],
                                     high=df['high'],
                                     low=df['low'],
                                     close=df['close'])])
fig.show()
```

[image]

Tried this:

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df.index,
                                     open=df['open'],
                                     high=df['high'],
                                     low=df['low'],
                                     close=df['close'], log_y=True)])
fig.show()
```

But... error...

```
Did you mean "low"?

ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Candlestick: 'log'
    ...
Bad property path:
log_y
^^^
```

Comment: In the graph object candlestick specification, `log_y=True` is not a parameter. It can be set in the form of updating the axis, but it will not be valid for candlesticks. `fig.update_yaxes(type='log')` I think this is the answer.